# How to count one to many

Tags: sql

i have two tables one `Job Category` with the structure `| id | name |` and the other one `jobs` with the structure `| id | job_name | job_category |`

How to count how many jobs are in each category?

Comment: show your work so that we can point you to a right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.name, count(j.id)
from job_category c
left join jobs j on j.job_category = c.name
group by c.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need join at all? Is it not

```
select job_category, count(*)
from jobs
group by job_category
```

If not, do post your own query (and, possibly, some sample data which might help us help you).

**[EDIT, after reading comments]**

It appears that my (over)simplified "solution" lacks in some details. True, it shows categories with no jobs, while the OP asked that those should also be displayed having "0" as a result.

Outer join with appropriate COUNT function would fix that; here's an example.

```
SQL> with job_category(id, name) as
  2    (select 1, 'categ 1' from dual union
  3     select 2, 'categ 2' from dual
  4    ),
  5  job (id, job_name, job_category) as
  6    (select 100, 'job 1', 1 from dual union
  7     select 200, 'job 2', 1 from dual
  8    )
  9  select c.name, count(j.id)
 10  from job_category c left join job j on j.job_category = c.id
 11  group by c.name
 12  order by c.name;

NAME    COUNT(J.ID)
------- -----------
categ 1           2
categ 2           0

SQL>
```

Comment: This will exclude categories with no jobs.

Comment: when a category has no jobs i wanna return 0. is it possible?

Comment: Right; @juergen & Terchila Marian, I've applied both of your suggestions & modified the message I initially posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a left join (see other answers) or with a subquery:

```
SELECT
    c.Name
,   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobs j WHERE j.category_id=c.id) AS Count
FROM job_category c
```